# Ion-refresher-content nothing shown

Tags: ionic3

Here is the code:

```
 <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
  <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="{{ 'PULL_TO_REFRESH' | translate }}" refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="{{ 'REFRESHING' | translate }}">
  </ion-refresher-content>                    
 </ion-refresher>
```

But nothings are shown, anyone know what is the problem?
My ionic info:

```
cli packages:

@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.5.0 (/Users/nulra/Downloads/proj3/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova)   
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.0 (/Users/nulra/Downloads/proj3/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular)   
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.6.0 (/Users/nulra/Downloads/proj3/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils)     
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.6.0 (/Users/nulra/Downloads/proj3/node_modules/ionic)

global packages:

Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.2  
Cordova Platforms  : browser 4.1.0 ios 4.4.0   
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.2
```

The doRefresh function:

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    refresher.complete();
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Any idea or someone have faced same issue before? thanks~

Comment: do you mean content is not shown? or the pull action?

Comment: the pull action are working, just the pulling text, pulling icon not show

Comment: can you add the `dorefresh` function to the question

Comment: Hi suraj, I have added the deRefresh function above

Comment: have you tried increasing timeout?

Comment: Yes still the same

Comment: Suppose when i pulling down the list i will see the animated arrow but it is blank

Comment: suraj, i have figuring out what is the problem, currently i put the ion-refresher in the ion-list, so it can't show the text, when i put it outside the ion-list, then it can show the refreahing content.